# How to store a string with special characters from a form to mysql database, using php?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

im using xampp

i used the `$_POST[]` to get the text from a text box in a form file to store it in a table.

if the text entered in the form contains any of these characters `(,.?' " \ ; :> <!...)` it returns an error message like this,

`Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's missile_carrier?' at line 3`

The entered text was `"China hails: first; test of-hypersonic nuclear's missile_carrier?"`

how to make it accept the text with these characters `((,.?' " \ ; :> <!...)`...

pls help

Comment: Switch to MySQLi / PDO (if you are still using the deprecated, old, `mysql_*` functions) and use parameterized queries.

Comment: you can use mysqli prepared statement to insert data

Comment: can u pls be a little more elaborate

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO resource (date, title, country, field, impact, reference)
VALUES
('$_POST[$date]','$_POST[$title]','$_POST[$country]','$_POST[$field]','$_POST[$impact]','$_POST[$reference]')";

Comment: i used the above code to get it from a form in another file

Comment: Your code has a security vulnerability called SQL injection. Once you fix it, your problem will go away. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/32775 for a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As advised please use mysqli and then use mysqli_real_escape_string
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php